# How to describe typeorm separate definition schema for mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, schema, typeorm

I try to create separate definition schemas on TypeOrm for MongoDb, but I face some problems.
Now my code looks like

**Base abstract entity class**

```
export abstract class BaseEntity<TProps> {
    // @ts-ignore
  _id: string;
  // @ts-ignore
  public props: TProps
}
```

**UserType class**

```
export abstract class UserTypeBase extends BaseEntity<IUserTypeProps> {
  @property('name') name: string = "";
  protected constructor({...props}: IUserTypeProps) {
    super();
    this.name = props.name;
  }
}

export class UserType extends UserTypeBase {
  public static Customer = UserType.Create({name: "Customer"} as IUserTypeProps)
  public constructor({...props }: IUserTypeProps) {
    Guard.NotNullOrUndefined(props);
    super(props);
  }

  protected static Create(props: IUserTypeProps): UserType {
      Guard.NotNullOrUndefined(props);
      const instance = new UserType(props);
      return instance;
  }
}
```

**TypeOrm Schemas**

**Base entity**

```
export const BaseEntitySchema = new EntitySchema<BaseEntity<any>>({
  target: BaseEntity,
  name: "BaseEntity",
  columns: {
    _id: {
      primary: true,
      generated: "uuid",
      type: 'uuid',
    },
  },
  // NEW: Inheritance options
  inheritance: {
    pattern: "STI",
    column: "type",
  },
  indices: [
    {
      name: "IDX_ID",
      unique: true,
      columns: ["_id"],
      sparse: false,
    },
  ],
  uniques: [
    {
      name: "UNIQUE_ID",
      columns: ["_id"],
    },
  ],
})
```

**UserType Schemas**

```
export const UserTypeBaseSchema = new EntitySchema<UserTypeBase>({
  target: UserTypeBase,
  name: "UserTypeBase",
  columns: {
    ...BaseEntitySchema.options.columns,
    name: {
      type: String
    },
  },
  inheritance: {
    pattern: "STI",
    column: "type",
  },
})

export const UserTypeSchema = new EntitySchema<UserType>({
  target: UserType,
  name: "UserType",
  type: "entity-child",
  columns: {
    ...UserTypeBaseSchema.options.columns,
  },
})
```

and request to database

```
const repository = MongoDbDataSource.getRepository(UserTypeSchema);
let userType : UserType = new UserType({name:"TestUser"});
await repository.insert(userType);
```

When I make a request I get an error like

```
Error in specification { name: "IDX_ID", unique: true, sparse: false, background: null, key: { _id: 1 } } :: caused by :: *The field 'background has value background: null, which is not convertible to bool*
MongoServerError: Error in specification { name: "IDX_ID", unique: true, sparse: false, background: null, key: { _id: 1 } } :: caused by :: The field 'background has value background: null, which is not convertible to bool
```

As I understand it, is that I am well pointing out a *background* value inside *indices* field of BaseEntitySchema near to  *sparse: false*, but  [EntitySchemaIndexOptions](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/interfaces/_entity_schema_entityschemaindexoptions_.entityschemaindexoptions) doest have definition  *background*  in addition, in version 4.2 mongodb canceled background indexes.As a database I use MongoDb 6.0.

Are there any ways to solve this problem or is it possible to describe the scheme in some other way? Sorry for my bad English. Thank you.